# Android service that gets JSON strings from web

Tags: android, android-service

I need to realize an Android app that receives notifications from a website/web service.

I think to write an Android service that can run in the background. To be able to receive messages. I don't know the best way to handle it. Is it better to poll every `n` seconds the server or is there a better solution like a Broadcast Receiver for custom messages?

Comment: how abot trying GCM (google cloud messaging)

Comment: Periodic service: what is your business goal? Time after which an update is required? Every second request might end up blocking you from server side.

Comment: It should be a realtime app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), anything else will waste power.

This will send your Application an Intent when your server tells Google to do so.

Comment: Thanks for GCM suggestion, didn't know about it.